# MySQLdb query not working in python

Tags: python, mysql

I am working in python and i am trying to create a database and then a table to populate data everything works but when i try to insert the data in that table it does not populate in table.

Here is my code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="123edcde")
c = db.cursor()

c.execute('create database if not exists testMovies')
db.select_db('testMovies')

sql = '''CREATE TABLE `testMovies`.`moviesDB` ( 
        `cinema_id` INT(20) NULL DEFAULT "0" ,
        `movie_id` VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
        `added` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
        `showtime` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
        `theatre` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
        `lang` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB;'''
try:
    c.execute(sql)
except:
    pass

sql = '''INSERT INTO `moviesDB`(`cinema_id`, `movie_id`, `added`, `showtime`, `theatre`, `lang`) VALUES ("1","why is","it","not","working","?")'''
print c.execute(sql)
```

When i tried to print as well as execute the insert statement, it returns
"1", means it was successful but when i try to check the row, i find table stays empty. I have manually tried executing this insert command and it works but i do not know why it is not working with python script in my development ubuntu 14.04 server.

Comment: You forgot the commit

Comment: Are you also doing `db.commit()`?

Comment: where do you tell the db to save your insert, via a `commit`?

Comment: is it important to close the cursor and also db connection after the execution?

Comment: Yes it is important.